# ASP.NET : How do I fetch data from a webserver every few minutes

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I need to fetch CSV file from a webserver every few minutes.

Here's what I am planning to do:
I will create a webservice "GetCSV.asmx" which will get CSV file from that webserver.

I will create another webservice "RegularCall.asmx" which will call "GetCSV.asmx" every few minutes.

Is my approach correct? Is there a better way of doing this?

I am using ASP.NET web application and JSON webservice for this.

NOTE: There will be NO user intervention and the solution I am looking for is similar to scheduling a task on the server...Can you please suggest a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know that you don't need to create different asmx files. You can create one and access individual methods within it.

Answer (score 4):

If you can do it from a client side call, use [jQuery $.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) and [javascript setTimer](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjs%2Fjs_timing.asp&rct=j&q=setTimer%20javascript&ei=ehk5TfHuDpO6sAPRgu2eAw&usg=AFQjCNFkWK5XLaslzcd5uM3rUtr3fyjP0Q&cad=rja) to pull on interval. Set the ajax call to load the web service.

Comment: instead of $.ajax, use $.getJSON as the asker mentioned that he is using JSON service.

Comment: I need this webservice to operate automatically without any user intervention. In that case, will jQuery $.ajax or json work?

Comment: Do you mean it needs to work without intervention while the user has an active browser window open at your url? If so, either $.ajax or $.getJson will work. I stick with $.ajax as it has the most flexibility. If no active user connection, then maybe you mean to use a scheduled task from your hosting provider? (or maybe I'm just confused... which is totally possible. ;D)

Comment: @Chad, I am looking something similar to a scheduled task. Can you please tell me whether jQuery $.ajax / json will work in that case? If not, what could be a better option?

Comment: Once deployed on the server, webservice will be in a kind of endless loop, fetching csv file every few minutes.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to build a page that when hit (probably with authentication) it would do it's work. Then you setup a scheduled task on your host to hit that page at the interval you want. No need for javascript at all... I was assuming you wanted it to do this while the client had the page open.

Answer (score 1):

Chad is right and this is a way you can call the [ASMX WebService from JQuery](http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/jalpesh/archive/2010/08/29/calling-an-asp-net-web-service-from-jquery.aspx). You just need to use,

```
<script language="JavaScript">
     setInterval( "CallWebServiceFromJquery()", 300000 );  
</script>

instead of 

OnClientClick="CallWebServiceFromJquery()"
```

**Note**: 300000 miliseconds = 5 minutes

I hope it would be helpful to you.

Comment: I need this webservice to operate automatically without any user intervention. In that case, will jQuery $.ajax or json work?

Comment: @meetpd put an alert instead of $.ajax and 1000 miliseconds and you'll see what's gonna happen